# Gevent: how to wait for set of greenlets finished

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets

I have a gevent.pool (with fixed size) shared between several task producers. Every task producer can apply a new greenlet to the pool if there are free slots. After tasks were added to the pool the task producer should wait until all added tasks are finished.

I tried to use gevent.queue.JoinableQueue to wait until all tasks are done. It works except I get a very annoying exception at the end of waiting.

How can I fix the code below to avoid that?
Maybe I do something wrong?

```
from gevent import monkey, sleep; monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.queue import JoinableQueue
from gevent.pool import Pool

pool = Pool(3)


def worker(n):
    print 'Worker {} started'.format(n)
    sleep(1)
    print 'Worker {} finished'.format(n)
    return n


def main():
    results = []

    queue = JoinableQueue()
    for job_no in range(5):
        pool.wait_available()
        greenlet = pool.apply_async(worker, kwds=dict(n=job_no), callback=lambda ret: results.append(ret))
        queue.put(greenlet)
        sleep(.05)
    print 'All workers added'

    queue.join()
    print 'All workers finished', results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Worker 0 started
Worker 1 started
Worker 2 started
Worker 0 finished
Worker 3 started
Worker 1 finished
Worker 4 started
All workers added
Worker 2 finished
Worker 3 finished
Worker 4 finished
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 27, in main
    queue.join()
  File "C:\Python\2.7.10\x64\lib\site-packages\gevent\queue.py", line 492, in join
    return self._cond.wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python\2.7.10\x64\lib\site-packages\gevent\event.py", line 219, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Python\2.7.10\x64\lib\site-packages\gevent\event.py", line 129, in _wait
    gotit = self._wait_core(timeout)
  File "C:\Python\2.7.10\x64\lib\site-packages\gevent\event.py", line 106, in _wait_core
    result = self.hub.switch()
  File "C:\Python\2.7.10\x64\lib\site-packages\gevent\hub.py", line 630, in switch
    return RawGreenlet.switch(self)
gevent.hub.LoopExit: ('This operation would block forever', <Hub at 0x26c1c28 select default pending=0 ref=0>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 'This operation would block forever' error because there is no greenlet to consume tasks in the queue, `queue.join()` just blocks until all greenlets have finished, then the exception raised.

`JoinableQueue` is not needed here, use `gevent.joinall()` to wait for all the greenlets to finish:

```
import gevent

def main():
    results = []
    gs = []
    for job_no in range(5):
        greenlet = ..
        gs.append(greenlet)
    gevent.joinall(gs)
    print 'All workers finished', results
```